# Derby creating project

Tags: node.js, npm, derbyjs

I'm working behind a company proxy, when trying to create a new derbyjs project, I get the error that it is trying to install dependencies

here is the section of the error.

Installing dependencies. This may take a little while...

npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express/3.0.0beta4

npm ERR! Error: Invalid protocol

npm ERR!     at Request.init (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:302:31)

npm ERR!     at new Request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:103:8)

npm ERR!     at request (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\main.js:956:11)

npm ERR!     at RegClient.makeRequest (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\req
uest.js:199:13)

npm ERR!     at RegClient. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:116:17)

npm ERR!     at RetryOperation.attempt (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\retry\lib\retry_operation.js:56:8)

npm ERR!     at RegClient.regRequest [as request] (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\request.js:113:13)

npm ERR!     at RegClient.get_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:112:8)

npm ERR!     at RegClient. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-client\lib\get.js:39:15)

npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!

Answer (score 1):

It is not derby issue, but npm issue. Though it is hard to guess reason, I think it`s somehow connected with your company network settings.